# Fundamental group of $S^1\vee S^1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I want to show that $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1) = \mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}. $ I know that it follows from the Seifert-van Kampen theorem, but we haven't talked about that in class.

We are given the following hint:

> Define a group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}\to\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)$ via the two inclusions $S^1\to S^1\vee S^1,$ and show that this is an isomorphism.

We've also never talked about free products, so I am very confused as to how to define this homomorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The left hand side is the free group on two letters, say $a$, $b$.  In terms of generators and relations, this free group is generated by two elements $a$ and $b$ subject to *no* nontrivial relations.  A typical element of this group looks like $aba^{-2}b^3 a^{-1} b$, i.e., a word in $a$, $b$, $a^{-1}$, and $b^{-1}$, and the group operation is given by concatenation.

Free groups also enjoy a very nice universal property.  In your case, 
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Grp}}(\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}, \pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1)) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Set}}(\{1,2\}, \pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1)),$$ that is, a group homomorphism out of $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$ corresponds to the choice of any two elements in the codomain, and vice-versa.

The two inclusions $S^1 \hookrightarrow S^1 \vee S^1$ precisely give you two elements on $\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1)$, which is exactly the data of a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z} \to \pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1)$.  In terms of the generators given above, this homomorphism is determined by sending $a$ to one of the two loops and $b$ to the other loop.

Comment: So if we let $i,j$ be the injections, $\alpha,\beta$ loops based at $x_0$ on each copy of $S^1,$ then $\alpha\circ i,\beta\circ j$ are maps $S^1\to\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)$. So then we want to send $a\mapsto [\alpha\circ i]$ and $b\mapsto[\beta\circ j]$, yeah?

Comment: The inclusions $i$ and $j$ are maps $S^1 \to S^1 \vee S^1$, so $[i]$ and $[j]$ are already elements of $\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1)$.  The homomorphism sends $a \mapsto [i]$ and $b \mapsto [j]$.   I don't know what you mean by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ other than $i$ and $j$.

Comment: Then as Omnomnomnom suggests, $[i]_*$ and $[j]_*$ generate $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)$, which implies surjectivity. Would injectivity come from the fact that any element of $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ is a word in $a,b$, so the image is a word in $[i],[j]$, which can't be in the same class as the constant loop since $S^1$ is  not simply connected?

Comment: I don't think you've addressed why a nontrivial word necessarily corresponds to the class of a nontrivial loop.  The usual proof, as you've noted, is via the Seifert-van Kampen theorem, and Omnomnomnom quoted half of the theorem in his answer.  The other half says that the kernel of the homomorphism has to do with $\pi_1(U \cap V)$, which in this case is $0$.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't like the Seifert-van Kampen theorem, you could try looking for the universal cover of $S^1 \vee S^1$ and studying its group of Deck transformations.

Answer (score 1):

Present the group $\Bbb Z * \Bbb Z = \langle a,b \rangle$.  It suffices to define our map on the generators $a,b$.

Let $L(S^1 \vee S^1)$ denote the group of loops over composition, and $\sim$ be the homotopy equivalence relation so that $\pi_1(X) = L(X)/\sim$.  Let $f$ be a map that sends $a$ to a loop around the first copy of $S^1$ send $b$ to a loop around the second copy of $S^1$.  Our homomorphism is $\pi_\sim \circ f$.

The trick is to show that this is an isomorphism.  How you do so depends on your tool set.  It's likely you have a theorem which looks something like this:

> **Theorem 59.1:** Suppose $X = U \cup V$, where $U,V$ are open sets of $X$.  Suppose that $U \cap V$ is path connected, and that $x_0 \in U \cap V$.  Let $i$ and $j$ be the inclusion mappings of $U$ and $V$ respectively into $X$.  Then the images of the induced homomorphisms
>   $$
> i_*: \pi_1(U,x_0) \to \pi_1(X,x_0) \qquad 
> j_*: \pi_1(V,x_0) \to \pi_2(X,x_0)
> $$
>   generate $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ *(Munkres, "Topology" (Second Edition))*

As it applies to our problem: the key is that every loop through $x_0$ (the intersection of our two circles) can be written as the composition of finitely many loops that "simple loops", i.e. those that begin and end at $x_0$ without passing through it again.  With that, we'll see that the homomorphism is surjective.

not sure about injectivity, though.